# Create Map from existing Map in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a Map

```
[email:[hus@gmail.com, vin@gmail.com], jobTitle:[SE, SD], isLaptopRequired:[on, on], phone:[9908899876, 7765666543], name:[hus, Vin]]
```

for which i need to have a another Map like

```
[hus:[hus@gmail.com,SE,99087665343],vin:[vin@gmail.com,SE,7765666543]]
```

How can do it in Groovy?

Comment: I'm guessing your "sample output" is wrong?  Do you really mean to have SE in both resulting values?  Also, where is the isLaptop data in the result?  Is the name "Vin" misspelled in the initial Map, or are you getting the keys to your map from the email addresses?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like:

```
def map = [email:['hus@gmail.com', 'vin@gmail.com'], jobTitle:['SE', 'SD'], isLaptopRequired:['on', 'on'], phone:['9908899876', '7765666543'], name:['hus', 'Vin']]

def result = [:]

map.name.eachWithIndex { name, idx ->
  result << [ (name): map.values()*.getAt( idx ) - name ]
}

assert result == [hus:['hus@gmail.com', 'SE', 'on', '9908899876'], Vin:['vin@gmail.com', 'SD', 'on', '7765666543']]
```

Or, you could also do:

```
def result = [map.name,map.findAll { it.key != 'name' }.values().toList().transpose()].transpose().collectEntries()
```

But this is just less code at the expense of both readability and resource usage ;-)

Comment: Tim, does Groovy have a known order of the keys or a Map?  If not, how are you specifying what order the values will come back in?

Comment: @BillJames By default, Groovy uses `LinkedHashMap` for maps, so order is maintained

Answer (score 0):

The most visual solution i have:

```
    def map = [email:['hus@gmail.com', 'vin@gmail.com'], jobTitle:['SE', 'SD'], isLaptopRequired:['on', 'on'], phone:['9908899876', '7765666543'], name:['hus', 'Vin']]


    def names = map.name
    def emails = map.email
    def jobTitles = map.jobTitle
    def isLaptopRequireds = map.isLaptopRequired //sorry for the variable name
    def phones = map.phone

    def result = [:]
    for(i in 0..names.size()-1) {
        result << [(names[i]): [emails[i], jobTitles[i], isLaptopRequireds[i], phones[i]]]
    }
    assert result == [hus:['hus@gmail.com', 'SE', 'on', '9908899876'], Vin:['vin@gmail.com', 'SD', 'on', '7765666543']]
}
```